# Plotting points on a rectangular grid with Paraview

Tags: plot, grid, gnuplot, visualization, paraview

I would like to plot the points contained in [this file](https://pastebin.com/Ese22k8R) with Paraview, but can't seem to figure out how to do so. Each column in this file corresponds to a set of 2048 points on a 64x32 grid. Each column contains sequences of points, one point per grid cell, each sequence is separated by an empty line space and corresponds to going over the width of the grid once (moving towards the y-direction and filling the x-points at each y-step). I would need to at least plot one column at a time, not necessarily all columns at once. In gnuplot, the needed plot is done with the command `splot "dat.25" us 1 wi li, "dat.25" us 2 wi li` (this command plots the points in the first two columns) and the plot looks like this:

[image]

This way gnuplot puts one point into one grid cell. So this grid is 64x32 and therefore there are 2048 entries per column.

I would very much appreciate if someone could please help with doing this sort of plots in Paraview. I've tried to experiment with all **Plot** filters, but have not so far found how to actually make a grid plot. But there should be a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such 3d plot in ParaView.

**Workaround** for a similar rendering

You can apply your data on a grid and then `warp` the grid with a data array

[image]

Steps to reproduce this example:

- load your data as csv (set delimiter to " " and check merge delimiters)
- apply a `TableToPoints` on it : check `2D Points` and `Keep All Data Arrays`. X, Y and Z columns does not matter: we do this only to create a Polygonal Mesh object.
- Create a Wavelet with extent

  0 - 63

  0 - 31

  0 - 0
- In the pipeline, select the Wavelet, then the TableToPoints with shift pressed, to have both selected
- Apply the `AppendAttributes` filter : this add your data on the Wavelet grid.
- Apply a `Warp By Scalar` filter with the scalar you want to see (you may change the scale, I set it to 10 in the screenshot)
- Set representation to `Wireframe`, activate the `Axes Grid`